# array1 is contain all value in array2 php pure looping and if contion

Tags: php, loops

create function to check array1 is contain all value in array2, if yes return true else false without php build function only pure looping and if condition

if sure my code is right but still there is no result in array2 with var dump function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to add your code.

Answer (score 2):

Hey if i understood your requirements correctly here is a code snippet.

```
<?php
$array1 = [1,2,3,4];
$array2 = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7];


function isInArray($needle, $haystack) {

    foreach ($needle as $index => $searchValue) {
        foreach ($haystack as $haystackValue) {
            if ($searchValue === $haystackValue) {
                unset($needle[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (empty($needle)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(isInArray($array1, $array2));
```